# Django performance - The mysterious 11 seconds

Tags: django, performance

I am having some performance problems that have left me baffled. I am using Django with MySQL. I do the following:

1 . Send data from a webpage using Ajax.

2 . Receive the post data in Views.py and process it via many function calls, inserting data into MySQL. The very first thing that I do is set a Python variable timeStart. The very last thing that I do, before returning a response, is calculate the time to process the data:

```
processTime = time.clock() - timeStart
```

I send a response using render-to-response where the response is processTime.

3 . processTime is displayed on the webpage.

processTime comes to 1.5 seconds, but the total time from sending the data via Ajax to receiving a response is 13 seconds. 11.5 seconds to render a simple page and to send and receive data - that's a long time. But then it gets weirder. I cut short the views.py function, almost immediately sending back a response. That cuts the processing time down from 1.5 seconds to almost 0. But it also cuts the total time down from 13 seconds to about 2 seconds. That would seem to indicate that it is, in fact, the data processing that is slow. However that does not explain that the calculated processTime only came to 1.5 seconds. I really do set startTime in the first line and calculate processTime in the last line. StartTime is not overwritten.

It's almost as though there is some kind of clean up process or something associated with finishing up and sending a response, something that is dependent on the function calls. But what? Or I am doing something stupid with my time calculation? I have set debug = False.

EDIT - extra info:

The template only contains the word "hello" and {{result}}. I'm not returning any queryset, just processTime: {'result':processTime}

The time difference seems to perhaps come when I am using MySQL stored functions. Like it's returning the result, but then still doing something????

Comment: I have had something similar, are you visiting localhost:PORT in your browser? try 127.0.0.1:PORT it solved slow POSTs on my system before

Comment: Thanks. I've actually uploaded my program to webfaction (an external server) and using my website there. I did not have these time differences on my own computer when using localhost, although it was generally much slower there - so I'll try this solution next time I'm doing tests on my own computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the way that I measured processTime. I needed to be using time.time(), not time.clock(). time.clock() told me that I had only spent 1.5 seconds, but that's apparently just the CPU time, not the actual time. The actual time spent in view.py was more like 13 seconds, which corresponds to what I had measured for the complete transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You have ORM/DB model queryset(s) that are being queried in your template render phase. This is not being counted by your view. The disk hit is causing that ~10 seconds.

Either that, or it is being triggered by your views via some ORM-related middleware doing further DB actions before sending back the HTTP response.

Turn on and check your DB logging.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given proper details of how you're returning the response, but I guess you're doing something like this:

```
data = MyModel.objects.all()
processTime = time.clock() - timeStart 
return render_to_response('my_template.html, {'processTime': processTime,
                                              'data': myqueryset})
```

So the calculation of processTime is very far from the last thing that happens in creating the response, since the *whole* of the template rendering takes place afterwards. There are two elements that you have discounted: the cost of rendering the template itself, which is far from cheap (Django's template language is not particularly efficient); and the cost of any database calls: as an example, the `MyModel.objects.all()` lookup I gave below won't actually hit the database until it's iterated in the template, so that would be after your processTime calculation.

In any case, you should investigate the Django debug toolbar, which gives you a much better breakdown of render time.

Comment: The template only contains the word "hello" and {{result}}. I'm not returning any queryset, just processTime: {'result':processTime}

Comment: What happens if you replace the render_to_response call with a simple `return HttpResponse(str(processTime))`?